# Read console text from background application in Linux

Tags: linux, console

I am creating an application that will kick off on the standard runlevel and basically run forever.  It will produce some console output that I'd like to be able to read selectively.  Is there a "correct" way to do this in *nix?

To be clear, the app will kick off as a background task.  I want to know if after it has started, I could "attach" and read the current messages being written to the console for that application.  I don't need the history, this would just be for debugging.

Comment: Why not just write or redirect the console output to a file?

Comment: If you do not want to store the output to a file, you could also use GNU screen. You can attach and detach the session and see what the program is doing. This works for instance: screen -d -m bash -c "watch date" # You can reattach with "screen -r.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way would be to redirect the output of your background task to a log file when you start it, and use tailf on it when you want to access it.

```
some_task > logfile &

tailf logfile
```

The tailf command will let you follow what is being written of the log file.

Comment: I was trying to avoid maintenance on the file if I could

Comment: @Spence The way Unix handles file indirections doesn't allow you to change from the 'outside' where the standards in/outputs of a program point to. That's why you have to take their control when you launch the program. Do you have a specific reason for wanting to avoid maintenance on the file? Maybe there's another workaround for it.